# Simple HTML DOM scrape character encoding issue

Tags: php, html, dom, screen-scraping

I'm trying to scrape some content from a website, which usually works perfectly fine. This time, however, when scraping the content I get a load of characters, little diamonds with question marks.

Both the website I'm scraping from and my own website are using UTF-8 as encoding. The strange thing is, that I can scrape the homepage of that site perfectly fine, but whenever I try to scrape a different page, it all get's messed up, even though these pages are using UTF-8 as well. To keep things simple I've only called file_get_html() and after that a simple echo $html->plaintext so there should be no errors in my coding.

Does anyone know how to solve this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Post some of the unwanted characters you're getting.

Comment: How are you verifying that the page is encoded in utf-8?

Comment: see answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12488111/php-curl-returned-html-all-messed-up